# stats does not work with spaces?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, stat

I am using a script to copy some files depending on the year they were created in, it works fine with files without spaces but with the files with spaces there is a problem with the stats command,for example i have this file : `file with spaces.pdf`

```
stat -c %y ./path/to/file\ with\ spaces.pdf|cut -d '-' -f 1
```

returns the year , for example :`2017`

but when used inside a script :

```
year=$(stat -c %y $pathfile | cut -d '-' -f 1)
```

it does not seem the work , and if i took the output of :

```
 echo "stat -c %y file | cut -d '-' -f 1"
```

and copy past it in a terminal it does work,the error is the same in all the cases, it's like ignoring this part of the file name :`with\ spaces.pdf`:

```
stat: cannot stat './path/to/file\': No such file or directory
```

I've tried adding quotes to the path,and it does not seem to work:

```
year=$(stat -c %y "$pathfile" | cut -d '-' -f 1)
```

I've seen somewhere that i need to place the stats in a function ,which i did:

```
 makestats () {
 $(stat -c %y $1|cut -d '-' -f 1)
 }
```

but it does not seem to work, i get the same error if you can give me your help that would be great .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote your variables in `bash`, not doing them will split your words in the variable to individual tokens and the command that uses that variable will be getting multiple words when it was expected a single string (See [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) in shell)

```
year=$(stat -c %y "$pathfile" | cut -d '-' -f1)
```

I suppose your problem is in your variable you are using `"` along with the `\` escape sequence. You need to do either of the one.

```
pathfile="/path/to/file with spaces"
```

Comment: I've tried this solution and it does not seem to work

Comment: @Kingofkech: it should work! What errors are you seeing with this?

Comment: The same error : stat: cannot stat './path/to/file\': No such file or directory it's ignoring the second part :/

Comment: @Kingofkech use either quotes ( " ) or backslash ( \ ), but not both.

Comment: @Kingofkech: Can you show the output of `$pathfile` variable?

Comment: this is the output: ./path/to/file\ with\ spaces.pdf , and i'm using both ,the \ and the "

Comment: @Kingofkech: That is the problem! See my update!

Comment: @Inian thank you sir , that helped me a lot :)